# Angular - Show as HTML in repeat block - do i need a filter?

Tags: angularjs

My API santizies and inputs coming in, so if I type:

`Green & Blacks` its saved as `Green &amp; Blacks` and subsequently thats how its appearing on my website.

Now i'm using `ng-repeat` where that text is displayed so I have something like:

`{{item.chocolate}}`

My question how do i get it to display as it should be `Green & Blacks`.

Do i need to write a custom filter then use it like or is there some simple built in way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a filter, just use ng-bind-html on a div or other DOM object.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

```
<div ng-bind-html="item.chocolate"></div>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/lwMAZQoBVtIfvTKtqEiP?p=preview

Comment: So if currently have `<li>{{item.chocolate}}</li>` this becomes `<li ng-bind-html="item.chocolate"></li>` ?

Comment: Yes or you could add the div in there if the <li> needed more DOM elements in it.